# How can I add `onsubmit="submitted=true;"` (property?) on my <form> if my javascript condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a `<form>` Its default property is `submitted=false;` and I have a statement

```
function checking() {
    var empty = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
       if (this.value == "") {
           empty++;
           $("#error").show('slow');
       }else{
         //missing piece
       }
    })
```

So when the user clicks the button and the above statement is not satisfied, I want to add `onsubmit="submitted=true;"` in my `<form>` and make it something like this `<form onsubmit="submitted=true;"`.

Comment: What is it that you expect adding that stuff to the form element will do?

Comment: Hi @Pointy!
This is my form-->

`<form action="googledoc-link" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" id="GoogleForm" onsubmit="submitted=true;">`

I want `onsubmit="submitted=true;"` to execute unless all my input textboxes in my form is filled up. Even though I have statement `function checking() {
    var empty = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
       if (this.value == "") {
           empty++;
           $("#error").show('slow');
       }else{
         //missing piece
       }
    })` Even an error is detected, thank page still show. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't get you wrong, you want to run that check and if it went well you want to set a variable named ***submitted*** to **TRUE**, and set it to **FALSE** otherwise.

If so, you could do it this way:

```js
function checking() {
   var empty = 0;
   $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      if (this.value == "") {
          empty++;
           $("#error").show('slow');
      }
   });
   if(empty > 0) submitted = false;
   else          submitted = true;
}
```

If that's not the case. If you wanted to **show an error** if there's an empty field and **prevent the form from submitting** if there's an empty field, so you should do it this way:

```
function checking() {
   var empty = 0;
   $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      if (this.value == "") {
          empty++;
          $("#error").show('slow');
      }
   });
   return empty == 0;
}
```